# npm prepare script not building folder in node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, npm-scripts

I am trying to use npm's `prepare` script to run a build step when npm installing from a different project.

The script does run during the `npm install` however, it doesn't build out the `dist` folder inside node modules.

Refer to this article for more details http://jim-nielsen.com/blog/2018/installing-and-building-an-npm-package-from-github/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same problem. My prepare script wasn't creating the build directory in the node_modules folder when installing as dependency.

Finally I found out that my .gitignore was the problem, which was setup to ignore the build directory for version control. NPM is inheriting the .gitignore file when no .npmignore can be found, which was the case here.

As stated on https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers:

> If there’s no .npmignore file, but there is a .gitignore file, then npm will ignore the stuff matched by the .gitignore file

So I solved the problem by simply adding an empty .npmignore in the root.

Comment: It's worth noting that `"files"` in `package.json` takes precedent over `.npmignore`, however the need for the build folder to be whitelisted (or not ignored) still holds true. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files

Comment: I encountered this issue in a slightly different form - my package was installing and building *some* of the files in my build directory. This solution fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to provide such a simple answer, but my solution was to use `npm install` rather than `yarn`, which apparently doesn't run the `prepare` script properly.