# Docker npm weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, typescript, docker, npm, node-modules

I'm using node module from GitHub, it's listed as

```json
"dependencies": {
  "bx24": "git+https://github.com/slntopp/bx24.git"
}
```

in `package.json`
When I'm running `npm install` on my local machine, module structure in `node_modules` looks like:

```
ui/node_modules/bx24
├── README.md
├── lib
│   ├── bx24.d.ts
│   ├── bx24.test.d.ts
│   ├── entities
│   │   ├── auth.d.ts
│   │   └── params.d.ts
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.js.map
│   ├── message-sender.d.ts
│   ├── message-sender.test.d.ts
│   └── utils
│       ├── parse-window-name.d.ts
│       ├── parse-window-name.test.d.ts
│       ├── unique-key.d.ts
│       └── unique-key.test.d.ts
└── package.json
```

Which is correct. But when I'm running same in Dockerfile, I'm getting only `package.json` and README:

```
Step 7/7 : RUN ls -l node_modules/bx24
 ---> Running in 3dcacee291aa
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1691 Oct 26  1985 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2552 Oct 23 01:06 package.json
```

So build fails with `Dependency Not Found`

I was trying to install the module in different ways, but none of them succeed, so I assume it's about module `package.json`, but can't find an issue.

Using the same version of node(12.18.2) on both local and docker machines.

Thank you in advance.

Link to Module on Github [here - https://github.com/slntopp/bx24.git](https://github.com/slntopp/bx24.git)

Also tried to update the module with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56082369/13872694, but it didn't help.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

ADD ./ui /ui
WORKDIR /ui
RUN apk add git
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

Exact build error message:

```
Step 6/8 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 750fd2283cbf

> ui@0.1.0 build /ui
> vue-cli-service build


-  Building for production...
Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors3:51:21 PM

This dependency was not found:

* bx24 in ./src/utils/bx24_loader.ts

To install it, you can run: npm install --save bx24
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ui@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ui@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-26T15_51_22_122Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Can you please attach your Dockerfile?

Comment: Hi, just attached

Comment: What does docker log show for the container?

Comment: Try to `ADD ui /ui`

Comment: You should not use `ADD` doe to the best practice guide: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy

Comment: I appreciate your Docker best practicals suggestions, but ADD cannot be an issue, since module is being installed freshly via npm

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum which log exactly?

Comment: `docker log your-container`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it fails on build stage, so there is no logs more. I've attached exactly error message to the topic.